# UIImageView is spilling outside collection view cells

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiimageview

[image][image]UIImage is expanding outside the collection view cell. The issue started when I added shadows to the cell.

The UI is done in code, when I added shadows to the cell specifically when I set maskToBounds on the cell to be false, the image expands outside the bounds of the cells.

```
    static let identifier = "kParameterCollectionViewCell"
    let bgView = UIView()
    let imageView = UIImageView()
    let nameLabel = UILabel()

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)

        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.autoresizesSubviews = true
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        self.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
        // Add Shadows
        self.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        self.layer.shadowRadius = 1.0
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
        self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 5.0, height: 5.0)
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false

        bgView.frame = self.bounds
        bgView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
        bgView.backgroundColor = .clear

        imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        //imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 2.0
        imageView.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.2745098174, green: 0.4862745106, blue: 0.1411764771, alpha: 1)
        imageView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.layer.masksToBounds = true
        self.addSubview(imageView)
```

I expect the image view to be on the far right of the cell.

I will try to post two photos, the first will be what is happening and the second will be what I expect.

Comment: Where do you add the constraints for these subviews, notably the `imageView`? You set `translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints` to `false`, but don’t appear to ever set the desired constraints it should use...

Comment: Did you use the View Debugger? It helps you debug views.

Comment: masksToBounds won't work with clipsToBounds, your Shadow is outside. Create container for your imageView and clip it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
```

Try with aspect fit.